# MaterialUI Select set value is always out of range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i've a MaterialUI Select code, and i'm handling the value parameter dynamically. My problem is, when i set any value, it says always it's out of range, even showing the value in the valid values.

```
SelectInput.js:291 Material-UI: you have provided an out-of-range value `100001,250000` for the select (name="followers") component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are `0,50000`, `50001,100000`, `100001,250000`, `250001,500000`, `500001,750000`, `750001,9007199254740991`.
(anonymous) @ SelectInput.js:291
```

And this is my code simplified:

```
const followers = [
  { '0-50k': [0, 50000] },
  { '50k-100k': [50001, 100000] },
  { '100k-250k': [100001, 250000] },
  { '250k-500k': [250001, 500000] },
  { '500k-750k': [500001, 750000] },
  { '+1M': [750001, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER] },
];

    <div className={classes.formGroup}>
                      <InputLabel id="followersL">Followers</InputLabel>
                      <Select
                        className={classes.field}
                        fullWidth
                        id="followers"
                        labelId="followersL"
                        margin="dense"
                        displayEmpty
                        name="followers"
                        onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)} //I've updated the sate with the new value
                        value={
                          filters.basicInfo.followers
                            ? value 
                            : ''
                        }
                        variant="outlined"
                      >
                        {followers.map((element) => (
                          <MenuItem
                            value={element[Object.keys(element)]}
                            key={Object.keys(element)[0]}
                          >
                            {Object.keys(element)[0]}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    </div>
```

As you can see in the message, the value selected `100001,250000` it's inside the range examples `100001,250000`

Where is the problem?

Comment: Check your componentDidMount method. For me the problem was that I was updating the state but the list used by the select was empty and only populated later down the line.

Comment: My problem was not including a defaultValue on the Select component. Adding ```defaultValue={""}``` worked.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This advice may be useful for others:
If the value for Select element is object, it should be the exact instance of the object from the list of Options.
For example:

```
const [test, setTest] = useState("");

//list of options for Material UI select
const testOptions = [
    {name: "123"},
    {name: "456"},
    {name: "769"},
];

//let's try to change value to {name: "123"} using JS
setTest(testOptions[0]);    // everything is OK
setTest({name: "123"});     // Error! You provided out of range value!
```

Comment: This is the real diagnosis to the question. The answers above telling you to stringify the object are merely a workaround. Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: I was starting to go crazy! thanks!
for others facing this problem: DO NOT create the list inside the component. I had the same issue and this was causing it. create the list outside, for example above the component function (if you are using function component).

Comment: Thank you so much!! for me all options were dynamic from API (`getServerSideProps`) and on each Next.js programmatic navigation I added a `useEffect` that sets the selected options again from the new array.

Answer (score 94):

add this defaultValue = "" like this
<Select
...
defaultValue=""
>

Comment: This resolved my warning 
"Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `undefined` for the select (name="stateForm") component."
Thanks

Comment: This is correct! Here is the MaterialUI GitHub resolved link to this warning: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18494

Comment: The same problem happened to me when I included an undefined variable in the field value=undefined_variable

Comment: I created a new <Select /> component within <Skeleton> and that was the dropdown where I had to add `defaultValue=""` prop. Thanks!

Comment: how does this work?

Answer (score 6):

Stringifying your value will get this to work.

```
element[Object.keys(element)] + ""}
```

If you needed it to be in its original array format before sending the result to your server you could use a function like this to do this

```
const strToArr = str => str.split(',').map(item => Number(item))
```

In my [code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-q2fuk?file=/demo.js) I have used your provided example and been able to replicate your error.  But Stringifying the value removes the error and gets it to work as expected.

```js
    
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const followers = [
    { "0-50k": [0, 50000] },
    { "50k-100k": [50001, 100000] },
    { "100k-250k": [100001, 250000] },
    { "250k-500k": [250001, 500000] },
    { "500k-750k": [500001, 750000] },
    { "+1M": [750001, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER] }
  ];
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = event => setValue(event.target.value);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>value - {value}</p>
      <div className={classes.formGroup}>
        <InputLabel id="followersL">Followers</InputLabel>
        <Select
          className={classes.field}
          fullWidth
          id="followers"
          labelId="followersL"
          margin="dense"
          displayEmpty
          name="followers"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={value}
          variant="outlined"
        >
          {followers.map(element => (
            <MenuItem
              value={element[Object.keys(element)] + ""}
              key={Object.keys(element)[0]}
            >
              {Object.keys(element)[0]}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From some research, what I've come to understand to be the reason for this warning, in my case, is the MUI Select was trying to map over a list of options that were not available on the first render as the list was coming from Axios response.

I made a component named `Dropdown` that renders the MUI Select component. I was providing it four props:

1. `options`: the list of options,
2. `initialValue`: the default value as I
   had different default values for different instances of the `Dropdown` component that were not the first item of the
   `options` list always

... and 2 other props that are not scoped for this discussion.

So, for each instance of the `Dropdown` component, I had to check whether the `options` list has any data, and only then render it. And this is what removed the warning from the console. To give a glimpse of what I did:

```
{viewsData.length > 0 && (
  <Dropdown
    options={viewsData}
    initialValue={7}
    {...otherProps}
  />
 )}
```

This was bugging me for a long time. Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Thank you for sharing this!
I solved it in a similar fashion like you did. First check if the options collection is empty. If true - set it with some temporary initial value.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem (you have provided an out-of-range value) when using a `number` state with a default value of `-1`:

```
const [selectedAccountId, setSelectedAccountId] = useState<number>(-1);
```

The solution to this problem was to assign an empty string for the `value` property in Material's UI `Select` component instead of using the default value of `-1`:

```
value={selectedAccountId === -1 ? '' : selectedAccountId}
```

Full component example:

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel>Account</InputLabel>
  <Select
    id="account"
    value={selectedAccountId === -1 ? '' : selectedAccountId}
    onChange={event => {
      setSelectedAccountId(Number(event.target.value));
    }}>
    {allAccounts.map((account, index) => (
      <MenuItem key={index} value={account.id}>
        {account.exchange} ({account.id})
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `value` should be `''` before `options` are loaded and then usually is an array of objects.

The cleanest way to fix this is add prop in your MUI `<Select>`:

- for controlled component: `value={options.length > 0 ? value : ''}`
- for uncontrolled: `value={options.length > 0 ? field.value : ''}` where `field.value` for example comes from `react-hook-form` from `<Controller render={({ field }) => ( ...` wrapper around MUI `<Select>`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and I solved it by making sure that the default value and the other select values thereafter are the same, for example if the default value is a string like `''` then the other values are `objects` it will show the warning so to avoid such a problem make the default value to be either a `[]` or `{}` or most preferably `null`

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Ait Friha Zaid response.

I also added the defaultValue attribute but also added an additional option:

```
const values = ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'];

 <FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel>{title}</InputLabel>
    <Select 
      defaultValue="choose"
      label={title} 
      onChange={e => func({...state, [keyName]: e.target.value}) }
    >
      <MenuItem disabled value="choose">Choose Option</MenuItem>
      {values.map((value) => (
        <MenuItem value={value} key={value}>{value}</MenuItem>
      ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

That way you always have a disabled option that works as a placeholder which is the default option, and in case you want to do form validation, until the user changes the option, the state wont be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use another approach since none of the solutions above worked for me.

I had to create the first element of the array I was going to use as the default to an actual value.  In other words, I was making the first element `''`, but it needed instead to be `' '`.  Setting a default value of `array[0]` where `array[0] = ' '` from the first item then worked.